# SharePoint 365 Share Sub Folder but root folder not visible

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-2013, sharepoint-2013

We have the following folder structure:

```
Folder A
------------Folder A.1
------------Folder A.2
------------Document A.1
```

I want UserA to be able to see Folder A.2 but nothing else in that folder. So I share Folder A.2 to UserA and using the link in the resulting email they can see the contents of that folder. However if they browse to the SharePoint site they can't see Folder A to then get to Folder A.2. What have I not done?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft say this is just the case, you need to keep the email notification for the link or bookmark it: https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/443958/1135803#1135803

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure permission inheritance.

- On the subfolder name, do the following:

  - Next to the subfolder name, click the Ellipsis…
  - On the file popup window, click the Ellipsis…, and then click Shared With.
  - To view the folder’s Permissions page, click Advanced.

    - Edit the permissions of those in the current list by selecting the check boxes and clicking either Edit User Permissions or Remove User Permissions.
    - Click Grant Permissions and fill out the dialog box.    Make sure you click Show options and select the appropriate permission level for the user

Comment: I have done that but Folder A does not become visible to the user. How are they supposed to browse to it? The only way is to click the link in the email but they can't keep doing that every time.

Comment: You need to add the permission to access folder A.1 for the user or group, then you need to set unique permission on folder A.1 . Set up permission inheritance on folder A.1 and add this user or group. Otherwise, rethink your folder hierarchy.

Comment: I tried that but then the user could see the whole directory listing inside Folder A. I only want them to navigate -> Folder A --> Folder A.2 without seeing anything else in Folder A.